# Editing @java.persitence.Table in external jaxb-Binding

Tags: maven, jpa, xsd, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I've set up a maven project to generate Java classes from a xsd-Schema. Firstly I configured the maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin (see the pom.xml snippet below), so that it can put the default JPA2 annotations in the entities. One of this annotations is @java.persitence.Table(name = "table_name"). I want to extend this annotation through an external global binding so that I can put the name of schema in it too. So that I would get @java.persitence.Table(name = "table_name", schema = "schema_name"). Is there a way to do this?
What about globally putting a prefix in the name of the table: @java.persitence.Table(name = "prefix_table_name"), any ideas how to do that?

Regards
Erzen

**pom.xml snippet**

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.6.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <variant>jpa2</variant>
    <extension>true</extension>
    <roundtripTestClassName>EKMSEnvelopeRoundtripTest</roundtripTestClassName>
    <args>
        <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
        <arg>-XtoString</arg>
        <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
    </args>
    <schemaExcludes>
        <exclude>ekvaattributes.xsd</exclude>
    </schemaExcludes>
</configuration>
```

**bindings-xjc.xjb snippet**

```
<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel">
    <!-- JPA-entities must be serializable -->
    <xjc:serializable />
</jaxb:globalBindings>


<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd"
    node="/xs:schema">

    <annox:annotate>
        <!-- my attempt -->
        <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.persistence.Table"
            schema="schema_name">
        </annox:annotate>
    </annox:annotate>

    <hj:persistence>
        <hj:default-generated-id name="Hjid">
            <orm:generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />
        </hj:default-generated-id>
    </hj:persistence>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lexicore Thnx for the help. After putting your suggestion in the right context it worked.

```
    <hj:persistence>
        <hj:default-entity>
            <!-- no need to overwrite the default generated table names-->
            <orm:table schema="schema_name" />
        </hj:default-entity>
    </hj:persistence>
```

Comment: For the SEO, I would have asked the question:
How can I change the default schema for all tables with hyperjaxb3.

Answer (score 3):

Author of [hyperjaxb3](/questions/tagged/hyperjaxb3) here.

See @Stefan's answer, just add the `schema="schema_name"` attribute:

```
<orm:table name="item" schema="schema_name"/>
```

`orm:table` is actually a JPA XML element so that's documented in the JPA spec. :)

See this schema:

https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/schemas/persistence/src/main/resources/persistence/orm/orm_1_0.xsd#L1814-L1815

I'm basically not inventing anything here.

You don't need JAXB2 Annotate Plugin for that, this works OOTB.

Here's an issue for the global prefix:

http://jira.highsource.org/browse/HJIII-87

Unresolved yet. Can be solved via custom naming now, but that's quite awkward.

https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/tree/master/ejb/tests/custom-naming

I agree, it would be nice to make it configurable.

**Update** How to do this globally:

```
<hj:default-entity>
    <orm:table name="item" schema="schema_name"/>
</hj:default-entity>
```

But you'll also need to customize defaults for associations and so on. See he built-in defaults here:

https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/plugin/src/main/resources/org/jvnet/hyperjaxb3/ejb/strategy/customizing/impl/DefaultCustomizations.xml

Comment: Hi, thnx for the answer. The problem with this solution is that I can't configure it globally for all classes of the compiled XSD and the XSD-s that are included in that XSD-schema. 

I want to generate the classes for different Java-Projects and I want them each time to use another schema-name. 
That's why I would like to configure the schema name globally for all the entities defined in my xsd and all imported xsd too.

Comment: Thnx for the help. After putting your suggestion in the right context it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is possible, but try the  element, maybe it has a 'schema' attribute, sadly it's not that well documented.

Regards,
Stefan

```xml
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd"
node="/xs:schema">
    <annox:annotate>

    <hj:persistence>
        <hj:default-generated-id name="Hjid">
            <orm:generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />
        </hj:default-generated-id>
    </hj:persistence>

    <!-- try this -->
    <hj:entity>
        <orm:table name="item"/>
    </hj:entity>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Source: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Customization+Guide

Comment: Hi, thnx for the answer. Unfortunately didn't solve my problem. For more info pls see the comment in the following answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may also define a schema for all entities globally in orm file referenced from persistence.xml. There is no need to copy schema into every `@Table` annotation.

persistence.xml:

```
...
  <persistence-unit name="MySchemaPU"  transaction-type="JTA">
     <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
```

And an orm.xml in META-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
                 version="1.0">
 <persistence-unit-metadata>

  <persistence-unit-defaults>
   <schema>schema_name</schema>
  </persistence-unit-defaults>
 </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings
```

Comment: Hi OndrejM, I thought about that too. But I want to generate two jar-files from this project and then use them in the same project. If I configured the schema name in the persistence.xml, I should use two data sources and I am trying to avoid that.