# Editing the name parameter of @java.persitence.Entity through external jaxb-Binding

Tags: maven, jpa, xsd, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I have the following constellation:
B1.xsd and B2.xsd both import A.xsd. Using *maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin* I created Java classes with JPA annotations for both B1.xsd and B2.xsd. So the classes of A.xsd are created in the project of B1.xsd as well es in the project of B2.xsd. 
In order to use this two sets of classes in one persistence unit, I set through jaxb external binding the database schema on each Entity, like shown in [Editing @java.persitence.Table in external jaxb-Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334881/editing-java-persitence-table-in-external-jaxb-binding).

The problem is, after deploying to wildfly, wildfly throws **org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: duplicate import: B1_ClassName refers to both B1_ClassName and B2_ClassName (try using auto-import=\"false\")"}}**

So what I need to do is editing the name parameter of the Entity annotation through jaxb external binding so that

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "B1_Element1")
@Immutable
@Cacheable(true)
@Entity(name = "B1_Element1")
@Table(name = "B1_Element1")
public class B1_Element1
    implements Serializable, Equals, HashCode, ToString
{
...
}
```

will look like

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "B1_Element1")
@Immutable
@Cacheable(true)
@Entity(name = "PACKAGE_NAME.B1_Element1")
@Table(name = "B1_Element1")
public class B1_Element1
    implements Serializable, Equals, HashCode, ToString
{
...
}
```

My actual *bindings-xjc.xjb* looks like this

```
<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel">
    <xjc:serializable />
</jaxb:globalBindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="B1.xsd"
    node="/xs:schema">

    <hj:persistence>

        <hj:default-generated-id name="Hjid">
            <orm:generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />
        </hj:default-generated-id>

        <hj:default-entity>
            <orm:table schema="B1_database_schema" />
        </hj:default-entity>

    </hj:persistence>

    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="b1.package.name" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

**Anybody has an idea how I can edit the name parameter of @java.persitence.Entity?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Hyperjaxb](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3).

The answer is that you should not need to customize this. I.e. if you need to customize this, something is wrong.

The problem that you're facing is because you generate two sets of classes for your `A.xsd` schema, probably in different packages. This can be the case if you're either have chameleon schema (`A.xsd` has no target namespace) or if you just compile it twice because you have `B1.xsd` and `B2.xsd`.

The correct solution is not to compile `A.xsd` twice. I hope you don't have chameleon schema (this is a very bad design pattern for JAXB). In this case you can either compile `A.xsd`, `B1.xsd` and `B2.xsd` together or you can compile all of the separately. You can compile `A.xsd` first and the use it as an episode in B1 and B2. See [Using Episodes](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Episodes) on how it works.

In any case you should not produce different packages for `A.xsd` classes.

To answer your specific question - try customizing your complex types with:

```
<hj:entity name="MyUniqueName"/>
```

I think this should override the automatically generated name. However that's not the way to go.

ps. Here's a test project for episodes:

https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/tree/master/ejb/tests/episodes

Comment: Hello @lexicore, thanks for your answer. I know this wouldn't be the best solution but doing crazy things with hyperjaxb is more fun than just using the standard solutions :)
Is there a way to edit the name parameter (for example giving them a prefix) of all the complex types at once? This would be helpful because I have almost 100 of those.

Comment: @Erzen Well, if you want hardcore, here's hardcore. You can write and configure your own naming strategy. Here's [an example](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/tree/master/ejb/tests/custom-naming). Implement/override `Naming.getEntityName(...)` method.